# Release Mode Create UI problems in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, release

[image: The gray thing above]

Whenever I run the app on debug mode it works perfectly. But in release mode, it shows this "gray thing" above of the UI. Why is this thing not showing in the debug mode? And what I have to do?

I need to publish the app tomorrow. and I am absolutely don't have any idea what to do now

Comment: The gray part signifies a UI error. You need to debug your app release mode so that you can get the error log

Comment: can tell me how to debug my app release mode?

Comment: `flutter run --release` will get you app running in release mode while you also get the debug logs

Comment: Thank you so much.. things are much clearer to me now.. And I'm solving the ui problems..thank you

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy fluttering!